# Deleting Columns that were Inserted with a Union

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code where I've inserted two columns through a checkbox multiple times (if user clicks box called Include_Weekends - two columns are inserted for duration of project). If the project lasts 10 weeks, then a union is created that inserts two columns 10 times to account for all 10 weekends.

For whatever reason I can't delete the inserted rows (when user unclicks the box) using the union and I have to resort to a loop as shown in my example. Is there a way to delete all the columns at once (in order to speed up code whereas the loop deletes each column individually instead of as a whole). Perhaps I am using poor coding practice as I'm still relatively new to VBA w/ excel so please excuse that.

```
Private Sub Include_Weekends_Click()

Dim myWeekendUnion as Range
Dim iWeekCount as Integer '# of weeks in project
Dim iFirstColumn as Integer 'First column in schedule
Dim xyz as Integer
Dim abc as Integer
iWeekCount = 5 'as an example... although this is user defined.

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Include_Weekends.Value = True Then
            Set myWeekendUnion = Union(Columns((iFirstColumn) + 5), Columns((iFirstColumn) + 6))

    If iWeekCount > 1 Then
         For xyz = 2 To iWeekCount
              Set myWeekendUnion = Union(myWeekendUnion, Columns((iFirstColumn) + (5 * xyz)), Columns((iFirstColumn) + (5 * xyz) + 1))
         Next xyz
    End If

    myWeekendUnion.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Else
    abc = iFirstColumn + (iWeekCount * 7) - 1
    For abc= abc To (iFirstColumnGantt + 6) Step -7
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(abc).Delete
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(abc - 1).Delete
    Next abc
End If 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert columns to the left of `myWeekendUnion` this set range shifts its address however many columns you added. So when you try to delete the range it is offset from your actual weekends. You should first insert the columns and then set the range of the weekends doing `Union`. Then you can simply call:

```
myWeekendUnion.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Cheers,

Comment: Is there no way to use the union to both insert and delete the columns?

Comment: The Union only defines the range set to the variable. When you have then the range you can do whatever( ie. delete columns or rows). But my bigger take away is that you have to insert the columns first and then set those cells to your range using Union. Let me know if further explanation is required. Regards.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not understanding... does this mean I should reset the union through the reverse loop I have in my code and then use the code you've provided once I've gone through that loop?